# Author email appears after abstract rather than on title page when using Revtex 4-1

Tags: revtex

I am using documentclass Revtex 4-1 with the preprint option and I'm attempting to provide the email address of the corresponding author on the title page.  Unfortunately, the email address appears after the abstract, which is on the next page after the title page.  How can I fix this?

I'm attaching a screenshot which shows that the email address is missplaced. [image] Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[preprint]{revtex4-1}

\begin{document}

\title{On the electrodynamics of moving bodies} 

\author{Albert Einstein}
\email{einstein@gmail.com}
\affiliation{Federal office for intellectual property \\ Bern, Switzerland}

\date{\today}

\begin{abstract}
It is known that Maxwell’s electrodynamics --- as usually understood at the
present time --- when applied to moving bodies, leads to asymmetries which do
not appear to be inherent in the phenomena. Take, for example, the reciprocal
electrodynamic action of a magnet and a conductor. The observable phenomenon
here depends only on the relative motion of the conductor and the
magnet, whereas the customary view draws a sharp distinction between the two
cases in which either the one or the other of these bodies is in motion. For if the
magnet is in motion and the conductor at rest, there arises in the neighbourhood
of the magnet an electric field with a certain definite energy, producing
a current at the places where parts of the conductor are situated. But if the
magnet is stationary and the conductor in motion, no electric field arises in the
neighbourhood of the magnet. In the conductor, however, we find an electromotive
force, to which in itself there is no corresponding energy, but which gives
rise—assuming equality of relative motion in the two cases discussed—to electric
currents of the same path and intensity as those produced by the electric
forces in the former case.

Examples of this sort, together with the unsuccessful attempts to discover
any motion of the earth relatively to the ``light medium,'' suggest that the
phenomena of electrodynamics as well as of mechanics possess no properties
corresponding to the idea of absolute rest. They suggest rather that, as has
already been shown to the first order of small quantities, the same laws of
electrodynamics and optics will be valid for all frames of reference for which the
equations of mechanics hold good.1 We will raise this conjecture (the purport
of which will hereafter be called the “Principle of Relativity”) to the status
of a postulate, and also introduce another postulate, which is only apparently
irreconcilable with the former, namely, that light is always propagated in empty
space with a definite velocity c which is independent of the state of motion of the
emitting body. These two postulates suffice for the attainment of a simple and
consistent theory of the electrodynamics of moving bodies based on Maxwell’s
theory for stationary bodies. The introduction of a ``luminiferous ether'' will
prove to be superfluous inasmuch as the view here to be developed will not
require an ``absolutely stationary space'' provided with special properties, nor
assign a velocity-vector to a point of the empty space in which electromagnetic
processes take place.

The theory to be developed is based---like all electrodynamics---on the kinematics
of the rigid body, since the assertions of any such theory have to do
with the relationships between rigid bodies (systems of co-ordinates), clocks,
and electromagnetic processes. Insufficient consideration of this circumstance
lies at the root of the difficulties which the electrodynamics of moving bodies
at present encounters.

\end{abstract}

\maketitle 

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1, if only for the text - much more interesting than `lipsum`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is intended behavior. If you want to include the email you could just force it to be next to the author as follows

```
\author{Albert Einstein (\url{einstein@gmail.com})}
% \email{einstein@gmail.com}
```

And then remove it and uncomment the second line when you are ready to submit.

Comment: Is this really intended behavior?  It's not easy for the reader.  The asterisk on the title page indicates a footnote, and then you have to look two pages later (the end of the abstract) to find the footnote.  The reader might then have to look back at the title page to remember which author had the footnote next to their name.

Comment: You have a point, but the current format is _consistent_ with how it is typeset when the option of preprint is removed.

Comment: I agree, this is very weird for intended behavior